# iOS start app at a "detail view" instead of RootVIewController created by Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, xcode7

Basically, I dropped a Navigation Controller, added 3 rows to the RootView's TableView, set a segue from the first row to a ViewController (The "detail view"). Now I want to start my app at this "detail view".
I tried to set the initial view as the "detail view", but it didn't worked. Latter I tried to trigger the segue, but I could not get it to work, and that solution seemed hacky, I decided to ask you people what would be the correct approach.

Thanks in advance for any reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set initial view Controller from appDelegate class.

And here is your code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // mainStoryboard
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // rootViewController
    let rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as? UIViewController

    // navigationController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController!)

    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true // or not, your choice.

    // self.window
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

And don't forget to assign StoryBoard ID from Identity Inspector and it will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use splitviewController to do the trick, if your app only runs on iPhone.

Drop in a splitviewcontroller and set it as the initial view controller.

Make the tableviewcontroller embedded in a Navigation Controller,and set the  Navigation Controller to be the master view controller of the splitviewController.

Make the detailviewcontroller embeded in a Navigation Controller,and set the navigation conntroller to be the detail view controller of  the splitviewController.

Then create the segue ,your storyboard should looks like this:

[image: storyboard]

For more details you can download the demo of Stanford cs 193p  Lecture 8:
[Psychologist VCL.zip](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Psychologist%20VCL.zip)